# Printing Lines in SAS filled by "."

Tags: string, sas, repeat

I have this code, but i think can be much easier

```
    
%MACRO Check_Global;

    %LET MaxLength = 35; 
    %LET Filler = %STR(..................................................);

    %DO i = 1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&V_Global));
        %LET Variab = %SCAN(&V_Global, &i);
        %LET Content = &&&Variab;
        %LET Padding = %SUBSTR(&Filler, 1, %EVAL(&MaxLength - %LENGTH(&Variab)));
        %PUT &Variab&Padding: &Content;
    %END;

%MEND;
%Check_Global;
```

RESULT:

```
Filter_UK..........................: '01'.'02'.'03'
Filter_USA.........................: '11'.'12'.'13'
......
```

Any other better and  faster way to fill the header Filter_UK?
Tried repeat but not working

Comment: To be nerdy, `%PUT` writes to the LOG.  Printing concept is more reserved for OUTPUT, generally files created by ODS.

Comment: Yes i know this, i have also a report that i send by email, but i need it in log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%put _global_;` will give you similar information.

If you're just looking for a slightly prettier version that you can filter, you could also use a DATA step, like:

```
%let V_global='SYSUSERID' 'SYSVER' ;
data _null_ ;
  set sashelp.vmacro ;
  name=transtrn(name,' ','.') ;
  where offset=0 ;
  where also name IN (&v_global) ; 
  put @1 name @33 value ;
run ;
```

Comment: WOW, very useful!! 
Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped.  Realized there  was no need for my code to create a new variable Name2, so I removed that line. This information about content of macro variables is available in SAS dictionary tables. If you go to lexjansen.com and search for "Dictionary Table" you'll find plenty of user papers, like https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2014/HT/PharmaSUG-2014-HT04.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

`%let Padding = %sysfunc(repeat(., %EVAL(&MaxLength - %LENGTH(&Variab))));` works well.

```
%let V_Global= _CLIENTAPP _CLIENTAPPABBREV; 
%Check_Global;
```

```
_CLIENTAPP..........................: 'SAS Enterprise Guide'
_CLIENTAPPABBREV....................: EG
```

Comment: Remember that the second argument to REPEAT() is the number of EXTRA copies you want.  So %SYSFUNC(REPEAT(X,1)) will return XX.  Also you do not need the %EVAL() for the numeric arguments to %SYSFUNC().

Comment: THIS WORK FANTASTIC!!!

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it works for you.